# Как выполнять код для каждого пользователя индивидуально в telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

```
flag = 0
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    global flag
    if flag == 0 and message.text == answers.answer1:
        flag = 1
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text.Win + '\n' + text.task2, parse_mode="Markdown")
    elif flag == 1 and message.text == answers.answer2:
        flag = 2
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text.Win + '\n' + text.task3, parse_mode="Markdown")
    elif flag == 2 and message.text == answers.answer3:
        flag = 3
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text.task4, parse_mode="Markdown")
    elif flag == 3 and message.text == answers.answer4:
        flag = 4
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text.lastTask, parse_mode="Markdown")
    elif flag == 4:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text.win)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твой ответ ложный, подумай еще')
```

Первый пользователь удачно проходит, а переменная flag = 4, второй пользователь уже получает текст, что он победил. Как сделать, чтобы для каждого пользователя переменная flag была уникальна? Либо как сделать, чтобы среда исполнения была для каждого пользователя уникальна?

Comment: Представьте пожалуйста код не скрином. А текстом.

Comment: Вставьте его в вопрос. А комментарий удалите

Comment: Тут без базы данных сложно обойтись :)

Comment: Да думал может массимов, где будет chat_id (пользователь) и flag (сколько прошел заданий). Но хотелось бы что-то получше